# section_label cannot be resolved (R.id.section_label)

Tags: android

this is my first post so I apologise if it is in the wrong place or if it has been answered. I am a beginner but have worked through most of the tutorials on Google's development site.

I decided to experiment with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html because it is closer to what I want to create but I am coming up with only one error. So being a beginner maybe I have missed something (although I am following to link from Google).

Here is the section that has the error...

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
```

On the 5th line, R.id.section_label is the issues. Thanks for any help you can give me :)

Comment: `Import yourPkg.R;` in your `Fragment`

Comment: @SimplePlan unfortunately that didnt do anything when placing the import packagename.R; at the top...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
Hit ctrl+shift+o to import anything if you are missing it. Make sure that the Id of the view that you are changing matches the actual Id. So go to the activity XML file and find the label and make sure it has the

```
@+id/section_label
```

If it's a problem with "R", that's a bug in Eclipse where the java files that should be auto-generated aren't being generated and you have to close the project and then reopen and clean it.